How to highlight cells based on my defined pattern
Experts, Please help this excel newbie

Admin        Developer      Subscribe
Contributor  Product Owner  Write
Viewer       Stakeholder    Create
             Test engineer  View
             Viewer         Modify
                            Assign
                            Add others
                            View history

Suppose if i click on admin cell the excel should only highlight the roles and permission associated with admin with any color
For example, Admin own the role product owner and his allowed permission is write and create that should be highlighted
Contributor has Developer and Test engineer role with write, subscribe and assign permission those alone has to be highlighted
likewise for viewer rest of the roles and permissions
I searched and found many conditional formatting options but I could not modify it according to this requirement
can anyone please help to achieve this specific highlighting pattern ?

There's no simple solution (AFAIK) to highlight the cells when you simply click on them (there's probably a complicated VBA solution).  If I understand you correct, you want to dynamically change the highlighted cell based on which one is selected, right?

Agreed, it can't be done the way you present the data. However, instead of clicking on a cell in column A, if you used a dropdown box to select which role you want to view then I can see conditional formatting using the result of the dropdown to determine if the cell should be formated or not.

@Srinath I am suggesting to look at this question, which achieves something similar via dependent dropdowns.

@Excellor, Thanks for the reply, Yes exactly m also referring some vba scripts for this but I am a begineer though.

@gns100, Thanks for the reply, I tried conditional formatting based on dropdown but it can only result the entire row or column not individual cells based on my input.

@karl Thank you for the reference I will try it out

@karl i could nearly reach the expected result, thank you
